# C++ - Smart Pointers - Casting smart pointers inside templates

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I have a complex code base at work, and i created a small example to mimic the problem and here is the below code.

< Code below for reference> - This code is compilable if we have boost libraries and FastDelegate.h linked with the project. Please let me know if you need the full compilable example project, i can email you.

I have two problems and need help resolving them.

1. As seen below in the code, i have a class with argument type as template for another classes object. Now when i initialize the class below in UserClass's constructor (Line 107) i get error because mBaseAcceptor is a class with template argument of type base Class, but i need to do mbaseAcceptor(new derivedAcceptor_t). Casting problem how to fix this?

Error here is

```
./boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:387:9: error: comparison between distinct pointer types ‘Acceptor<DerivedClass>*’ and ‘Acceptor<BaseClass>*’ lacks a cast
```

1. Another problem is in line 108, even if i magically say resolve this by using another acceptor of derived class, this is where i use that mDerivedAcceptor, in Line 108 i do

   ```
   mDerivedAcceptor->SetDelegate(fastdelegate::MakeDelegate(this, &UserClass::HandleDelegate));
   ```

then i get error saying

```
"error no matching function call for HandleDelegate(DerivedClass&, bool).
```

This make sense because HandleDelegate has argument of type BaseClass and by storing a delegate(which is a func. ptr) we have to call the function with appropriate argument. But how to fix this.

1. If i cast Handler inside Acceptor class with derived class will it work when i only pass the baseClass pointer?

Code

```
/*
 * smart_pointer_1.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jul 26, 2011
 *      Author: balaji
 */
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include "FastDelegate.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class Handler>

class Acceptor {

public:
    typedef fastdelegate::FastDelegate1<Handler &, bool> delegate_t;
    Acceptor ();
    void Initialize(Handler *&handle);
    void SetDelegate(delegate_t delegate) { mDelegate = delegate; }

private:
   int mValues[2];
    delegate_t mDelegate;
};

template <class Handler>
Acceptor<Handler>::Acceptor()
{
    std::cout << "In Constructor: " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    mValues[0] = 1;
    mValues[1] = 2;

}   

template <class Handler>
void Acceptor<Handler>::Initialize(Handler *&handle){
    if (!handle) {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " : created" << std::endl;
        handle = new Handler();
    } else {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " : Error exception" << std::endl;
    }
    if (mDelegate && mDelegate(*handle)) {
        std::cout << "Ok Called Handle in " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not Called Handle in " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

   handle->displayComputer();
}

class BaseClass {
    std::string mComputer;
public:
    BaseClass() {
    std::cout << "In Base Constructor: " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    mComputer = "Mac";
    }
    virtual void displayComputer() {
    std::cout << "Computer type is " << mComputer << std::endl;
    }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
    std::string mLanguage;
public:
    DerivedClass() {
    std::cout << "In Derived Constructor: " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    mLanguage = "C++";
    }
    void displayComputer() {
    std::cout << "Language is " << mLanguage << std::endl;
    }
};

class UserClass {
public:
    UserClass();
    UserClass(bool);
    typedef Acceptor<BaseClass> baseAcceptor_t;
    typedef Acceptor<DerivedClass> derivedAcceptor_t;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass> basePtr_t;
    void CallDelegate(BaseClass&);

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<baseAcceptor_t> mBaseAcceptor;
    boost::shared_ptr<derivedAcceptor_t> mDerivedAcceptor;
    BaseClass *mConnBasePtr;

    bool HandleDelegate(BaseClass& baseDelegate);
};

UserClass::UserClass() : mBaseAcceptor(new baseAcceptor_t)
{
    std::cout << "In Constructor: " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    mBaseAcceptor->SetDelegate(fastdelegate::MakeDelegate(this, &UserClass::HandleDelegate));
    mBaseAcceptor->Initialize(mConnBasePtr);
}

UserClass::UserClass(bool value)
{
    std::cout << "In Constructor: " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    mBaseAcceptor.reset(new derivedAcceptor_t);         //    <<========== Problem Here because of improper casting
    mBaseAcceptor->SetDelegate(fastdelegate::MakeDelegate(this, &UserClass::HandleDelegate));   //   <<=== Also here because of improper type passed to MakeDelegate function ptr. Please note HandleDelegate has an argument of type BaseClass, but Acceptor is derived class
    mBaseAcceptor->Initialize(mConnBasePtr);
}


bool UserClass::HandleDelegate(BaseClass& baseDelegate)
{
    std::cout << "In " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    return true;
}


int main() {
    std::cout << "In function: " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<UserClass> userPtr_t;

    userPtr_t user(new UserClass(true));

    std::cout << "In function: " << __FUNCTION__ << " at end "<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pleae post *the relevant* code here. SO has excellent code formatting capabilities, so make it easy for others to help you and post your code *here*.

Comment: @jalf - My bad, editted my post with the code. The reason i have the full code is because its easy to copy paste to analyze the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define base class for the Acceptor template and another class that will be base to all Handler types. So your implementation will change to:

```
class IHandler {
};  

class IAcceptor {
public:
    virtual void Initialize(IHandler *) = 0;
    virtual void SetDelegate(delegate_t delegate) = 0;
};
```

Your Acceptor template will change to:

```
template <class Handler>
class Acceptor : public IAcceptor {
public:
    typedef fastdelegate::FastDelegate1<Handler &, bool> delegate_t;
    Acceptor ();
    void Initialize(IHandler *pVal);
    void SetDelegate(delegate_t delegate) { mDelegate = delegate; }
private:
   int mValues[2];
    delegate_t mDelegate;
};
```

Your implementation for Initialize will change (Make sure you handle the dynamic_cast result correctly):

```
template <class Handler>
void Acceptor<Handler>::Initialize(IHandler *pVal){
    Handler *pHandle = dynamic_cast<Handler>(pVal); //You will have to ofcourse ttake appropriate action if this cast fails.
    if (!handle) {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " : created" << std::endl;
    handle = new Handler();
    } else {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " : Error exception" << std::endl;
    }
    if (mDelegate && mDelegate(*handle)) {
    std::cout << "Ok Called Handle in " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    } else {
    std::cout << "Not Called Handle in " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

   handle->displayComputer();
}
```

Finally all classes that have to be used with the Acceptor will have to be derived from IHandler.

Now you can change your pointer declaration to shared_ptr< IAcceptor >.

EDIT:

Based on your comment for the second issue, I would pass the Handler object as a pointer instead of a reference and modify the UserClass::HandleDelegate method to accept a pointer to the BaseClass (or the IHandler class if you want to be even more generic.).

Comment: Thnx gr8 thing, let me try out your idea. Thnx. The second problem is in initialize function i call " if (mDelegate && mDelegate(*handle)) {" this mDelegate is set via SetDelegate function of Acceptor class. which is called in UserClass. This is a delegate to the function "HandleDelegate" which has an argument of type BaseClass&. because i do mDerivedAcceptor->SetDelegate(MakeDelegate(this, &HandleDelegate), this throws an error because mDerivedAcceptor does new Acceptor which would new the derived class and not the base class

Comment: @devgp Look at the Edit in my post.

Answer (score 4):

`Acceptor<DerivedClass>` is not derived from `Acceptor<BaseClass>` (it doesn't matter that `DerivedClass` is derived from `BaseClass` or not) so the compiler can not cast one into the other.

I would get rid of the templatization of the acceptor, unless you have a good reason to keep it (which I don't see in your code) :

```
class Acceptor {
public:
    typedef fastdelegate::FastDelegate1<BaseClass &, bool> delegate_t;
    Acceptor ();
    void Initialize(BaseClass *handle);
    void SetDelegate(delegate_t delegate) { mDelegate = delegate; }

private:
    int mValues[2];
    delegate_t mDelegate;
};

void Acceptor::Initialize(BaseClass *handle){
    if (!handle) {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " : Error exception" << std::endl;
    }
    if (mDelegate && mDelegate(*handle)) {
        std::cout << "Ok Called Handle in " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not Called Handle in " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    handle->displayComputer();
}
```

Then you don't need separate `baseAcceptor_t` and `derivedAcceptor_t` types as they both become simply `Acceptor`, and you can do for example :

`UserClass::UserClass() : mBaseAcceptor(new Acceptor(new BaseClass))`

As far as I see the only thing you loose is the ability to pass a null pointer to the acceptor's constructor and have it create its handler itself. That's a very minor loss as the real decision (instantiate a base or a derived handler) is really taken when you instantiate the `Acceptor` anyway (because you choose which of `Acceptor<BaseClass>` or `Acceptor<DerivedClass>` you want)

Comment: Thanks, but how else can i do this. if you note here the only places where it matters to me with the handle is template <class Handler>
void Acceptor<Handler>::Initialize(Handler *&handle) .. and void SetDelegate(delegate_t delegate) { mDelegate = delegate; }, because the delegate function takes an argument of derived class

Comment: Do you really have to make Acceptor a template ? Can't it store a reference (or a shared pointer) to BaseClass which would be passed to its constructor ?

Comment: Yes the code above is just a stripped out example from our main code base. Acceptor actually does lot more things, So i still need to keep Acceptor the same thing. All i want is just to initialize the derived class when some condition is true and need to pass it to Acceptor which will actually do lot more things with it, than quoted in this example.

Comment: What I mean is, if Acceptor only care about the exact type of the handler (base or derived) at the time it is constructed (to construct the right type of handler) then you can do the handler creation outside of the acceptor and pass the newly created handler to the acceptor's constructor.

Comment: your comment was exactly what i had tried, but i was stuck at the second problem with delegate. In userClass(bool) constructor, i did - mDerivedAcceptor.reset(new derivedAcceptor_t);         // worked
    mDerivedAcceptor->SetDelegate(fastdelegate::MakeDelegate(this, &UserClass::HandleDelegate));   //   <<=== here because of improper type passed to MakeDelegate function ptr. Please note HandleDelegate has an argument of type BaseClass, but Acceptor is initializes derived class (please refer code above)
    mDerivedAcceptor->Initialize(static_pointer_cast derivedConnPointer);

Comment: That would also be solved by moving from templating to storing a pointer to the handler in the acceptor ... Using a template instead of a plain class looks like an unnecessary complication in your case. If Acceptor only deals with a reference (or pointer) to BaseClass, you won't have any more type problems with SetDelegate or HandleDelegate (no matter if the handler referenced is really a BaseClass or a DerivedClass ... that's polymorphism)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `boost::static_pointer_cast`, because even though

```
class Derived : public Base{};
```

it doesn't make `boost::shared<Derived>` inherit from `boost::shared_ptr<Base>`.
So you have to use explicit boost cast  like `boost::static_pointer_cast, boost::dynamic_pointer_cast` accordingly.